pywinrm CredSSP NTLM BadMechanismError(context_msg="Unable to negotiate common mechanism", base_error=last_err)
I am trying to debug strange behaviour when using the pywinrm. It cannot open WinRM connection because of
BadMechanismError: SpnegoError (1): expected string or bytes-like object, got 'dict', Context: Unable to negotiate common mechanism

I am using it in a docker and the same image behaves differently. Running the image on one server produces error message below, running on different server
I am not able to figure out what can be different
2024-06-27T14:38:56+0000 DEBUG _credssp MainProcess-10 MainThread-139775582927656 _step_initiate : Starting CredSSP authentication phase
2024-06-27T14:38:56+0000 DEBUG _negotiate MainProcess-10 MainThread-139775582927656 step : SPNEGO step input:
2024-06-27T14:38:56+0000 DEBUG _negotiate MainProcess-10 MainThread-139775582927656 _rebuild_context_list : Attempting to create kerberos context when building SPNEGO mech list
2024-06-27T14:38:56+0000 DEBUG _negotiate MainProcess-10 MainThread-139775582927656 _rebuild_context_list : Failed to create context for SPNEGO protocol kerberos: Configuration file does not specify default realm -1765328160
2024-06-27T14:38:56+0000 DEBUG _negotiate MainProcess-10 MainThread-139775582927656 _rebuild_context_list : Attempting to create ntlm context when building SPNEGO mech list
2024-06-27T14:38:56+0000 DEBUG _negotiate MainProcess-10 MainThread-139775582927656 _rebuild_context_list : Failed to create context for SPNEGO protocol ntlm: expected string or bytes-like object, got 'dict'
2024-06-27T14:38:56+0000 ERROR exception_handler MainProcess-10 MainThread-139775582927656 process_exception : (500) Exception occurred: Received error status from the server: (2148074245) UNKOWN_STATUS 0x80090305
2024-06-27T14:38:56+0000 ERROR exception_handler MainProcess-10 MainThread-139775582927656 process_exception : Received error status from the server: (2148074245) UNKOWN_STATUS 0x80090305
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests_credssp/credssp.py", line 105, in credssp_generator
    out_token = self._context.step(in_token)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/spnego/_credssp.py", line 367, in step
    out_token = self._step_gen.send(in_token)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/spnego/_credssp.py", line 396, in _step_initiate
    out_token = self._auth_context.step()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/spnego/_negotiate.py", line 148, in step
    mech_token_in, mech_list_mic, is_spnego = self._step_spnego_input(
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/spnego/_negotiate.py", line 259, in _step_spnego_input
    self._mech_list = self._rebuild_context_list(
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/spnego/_negotiate.py", line 475, in _rebuild_context_list
    raise BadMechanismError(context_msg="Unable to negotiate common mechanism", base_error=last_err)
spnego.exceptions.BadMechanismError: SpnegoError (1): expected string or bytes-like object, got 'dict', Context: Unable to negotiate common mechanism

These is requirements.txt and I am using python version 3.12:
Django==5.0.3
asgiref==3.8.1
asn1crypto==1.5.1
certifi==2024.6.2
cffi==1.16.0
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
cryptography==42.0.8
decorator==5.1.1
django-environ==0.11.2
djangorestframework==3.15.2
gssapi==1.8.3
gunicorn==22.0.0
idna==3.7
krb5==0.5.1
packaging==24.1
pip==24.1.1
psycopg2-binary==2.9.9
pycparser==2.22
pyspnego==0.11.0
pytz==2024.1
pywinrm==0.4.3
requests==2.32.3
requests-credssp==2.0.0
requests-gssapi==1.3.0
requests-kerberos==0.15.0
setuptools~=70.1.1
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.5.0
urllib3==2.2.2
xmltodict==0.13.0

I am asking for advice how to debug it, how to figure out why it is sometimes working and connection through the WinRM is established properly, and sometimes not. (especially running the same docker image)
Any clue?
